# How to share data between two component in vuejs with Event Bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I am trying to implement a global event bus in order to send a variable from component A to component B.

Here is the component A code:

```
data () {
            return {                
            commandes: [],
            }
        },

envoyer() {                                 
                this.$eventBus.$emit('commande', this.commandes);
            },
```

Here is the component B code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <!-- Table row -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Qté</th>
                      <th>Produit</th>
                      <th>Subtotal</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr v-for="(commande, index) in commandes" :key="index">
                        <td>{{ commande.quantite }}</td>
                        <td>{{ commande.produit_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ commande.montant }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data() {
          return {
            commande: [],
          }
        },

        methods: {         
        },

        mounted() {
          this.$eventBus.$on('commande', (commandes) => {
            this.commande = commandes;
            console.log(commandes);
          })
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting this error when component B is displayed:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "commandes" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the template part of component B?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you are referencing `commandes`

```
<tr v-for="(commande, index) in commandes" :key="index">
```

but your data doesn't return it, it returns `commande`

```
data() {
   return {
    commande: [],
   }
}
```

Update your data and bus listeners:

```
data() {
   return {
    commandes: [],
   }
}

...

this.$eventBus.$on('commande', (commandes) => {
  this.commandes = commandes;
  console.log(commandes);
})
```

Comment: Ok there is no more error, however the data is not displayed

Comment: are you getting any values from console.log?

Comment: i'm getting this: `Array []`. I think there is no data.

Comment: This means that you're not sending any data. But the bus is working

Comment: I have corrected the data problem now I get this in console.log(): `[0: Object { produit_id: Getter & Setter, quantite: Getter & Setter, montant: Getter & Setter, … }]` do you have an idea to loop through this?

Comment: my v-for does not display anything